# Access dev server inside unknown network from another device

Tags: reverse-proxy, ssh-tunnel, web

I am developing a website from a host on network A and want to access the server running there from a mobile device on network B.

I know nothing of the network topography, since it is internal enterprise stuff.

I imagine I should be able to create an SSH tunnel to some external server, which is accessible to both devices and then tunnel back the traffic from the mobile browser through there. Something link

- PC opens a tunnel from port 8000 to External:8001
- PC runs dev server on port 8000
- Mobile connects to External:8001 in its browser and actually accesses PC:8000

I haven't been able to achieve this though. At best, I've managed to open the tunnel, so that External can access PC:8000 through its localhost:8001

Comment: Why not use the devtools that comes with the majority of the browsers to check how the website is doing when a mobile user is connecting?

Comment: Simply because those tools aren't good enough. They do not simulate touch-events in the same way that the actual devices do, so they provide no guarantees of working properly. For responsive design and all that, it is fine

Comment: well, chrome does:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/

Comment: Alright then. Didn't have that the last time around. Will keep that in mind. Question still stands though